# Change tabs placement in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm pretty new to Ionic and I would like to put my tabs below a slider including images, is it possible?

I have already read the docs, posts forum but nothing really answer my question :/

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? What is blocking you?

Comment: Can you show the image of your page design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a tab component and page (or integrated as per the example)

First, use the command line to make a new tabs page;

```
$ ionic generate page MyNewPage
```

Then in your component (.ts) page add the following...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ionicBootstrap } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Tab1 } from './slider-page';
import { Tab2 } from './other-page';
@Component({
  template: `
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="heart" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="star" [root]="tab2"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>`
})
class MyApp {

  tab1: any;
  tab2: any;

  constructor() {
    this.tab1 = Tab1;
    this.tab2 = Tab2;
  }
}
```

You need to ensure you import the pages you wish to show on your tabs so change the lines as per the pages you have...

```
import { Tab1 } from './slider-page';
import { Tab2 } from './other-page';
```

In addition, you will need to change the 'modules.ts' file to import your tabs component and you should be all set.

More information can be found on the official ionic 3 documentation page; https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys,

RedCrusador, I've already done all of this, I think I expressed myself badly but thank you.

Here is what my app is looking: https://ibb.co/d84FXF
I would like to add a "carousel" between my header and my tab with a height of like 1/3 of the screen.

Thanks

Comment: If you have tabs working and want to change placement from bottom (default) to top then you need to add `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{tabsPlacement: 'top'})` in your src\app\app.module.ts file - does that answer your question?

Comment: If you look at my screen, I've already done the `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{tabsPlacement: 'top'})` thing. My question is, (sorry if you didnt understood me again, english is not my main language) can I move my tabs where I want ? Like on the middle of the screen ?

Comment: Ok the question was not at all clear. There is no ionic specificiation to do this, so as a fallback I would look as using CSS to acheive this. tabsPlacements changes .tab to position:absolute;top:0 so you could override this using something like position:absolute;top: 150px !important; Not tested, this should give you something to start with...

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it ! :)